# How to change picture file dimension in C#?

Tags: c#, image-resizing

I am working a mvc web app. I upload a image to use it as system logo. Now if I select image and upload it, it can be replaced easily until image file is not of large dimesion. For file with large dimension i need to reduce its size to some smaller size to make it look like a system logo. Preferable size for my logo is 100x75. How can I reduce the file dimesion?
THanks,
kapil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the classes that are in the [`System.Drawing`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.aspx) namespace.

See [this tutorial](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-image-editing-saving-cropping-and-resizing) for details.

Comment: The code snippet will likely bring your server down (or at least cause worker process recycling) on a high-traffic site, since it doesn't take care of releasing all the used GDI+ objects right away.

Comment: Use the http://imageresizing.net library. It's 1 line of code to use, and < 200K added to your assembly. And it avoids the [29+ pitfalls in .NET image resizing](http://nathanaeljones.com/163/20-image-resizing-pitfalls/).

Answer (score 3):

try this.
I found it in the msdn, and it works.

```
Bitmap map = new Bitmap(Image.FromFile("F:\\1.jpg"), new Size(20, 20));
map.Save("F:\\5.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```